# while loop argument not take into account

Tags: python

I have just begin to learn to program with Python and I try to make a rock-paper-scissor game to train myself.

I have a problem at the end of the the code with the while loop
It doesn't take account of my computer_score so if I have to create a variable and add an argument to not finish with an infinite loop

```
user_choice = "Rock"
user_score = 0
computer_score = 0


def fight(user_choice):
    if user_choice == "Rock":
        scissor = 1
        rock = 2
        paper = 3
        user_choice = rock
        computer_choice = randint(1, 3)
        print computer_choice
        if user_choice == computer_choice:
            print 'DRAW!'
        elif user_choice > computer_choice:
            print 'User win, consciousness can\'t be beaten, you win'
            global user_score
            user_score += 1
        elif user_choice < computer_choice:
            print 'Computer win, singularity has been reach'
            global computer_score
            computer_score += 1


i = 0
while (computer_score < 3 or i < 30):
    fight(user_choice)
    i = i + 1
```

Comment: Suppose `computer_score` is 50, and `i` is 15. Consider what `computer_score < 3 or i < 30` evaluates to in that situation.

Comment: As you're `prints` when the computer wins aren't specific to what it chose, you can just randomly print one of those `statements`.

Answer (score 0):

There may be the case that randint(1, 3) always returns 1. So computer never wins. This way your while loop continues infinitely.

Comment: This is incredibly unlikely, and not what's causing the OP's issue. @Kevin already identified the issue in his comment.